# Async CTP and Windows Azure Support

Tags: azure, async-ctp

Quick question, couldn't find a answer via google...

**Does the Windows Azure platform support Async CTP?**

Is it a matter of copying references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the Async CTP and then create an Azure project that references it. The Async CTP libraries are under My Documents - Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP - Samples.

Just use the regular AsyncCtpLibrary.dll for web or worker roles. I believe it'll be copied by default into your bin folder.

The async/await pattern can be used because it is only a compiler transformation. There is no special CLR support for async methods. Async CTP programs that have async methods run on the regular .NET 4.0 runtime.