# How to migrate Async CTP 3.0 project from VS 2010 to VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

We've got a bunch of C# projects that are using Async CTP 3.0 in VS 2010.  We'd like to standardise all our developer machines to VS 2013, which means moving to the 4.5 framework.

I know 4.5 is supposed to be a 'drop-in' replacement for 4.0, but not where Async CTP is concerned.

I'd like to manage the transition as cleanly as possible, and be prepared for any issues.

The only thing I've found that seems to be mention this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994834/2197391

With that in mind, I've got the following questions,

- Are there any gotchas involved?
- Is it simply a case of doing the following:

  1. uninstall Async CTP 3.0
  2. install VS 2013 (and framework 4.5)
  3. fix existing projects (rename TaskEx to Task, signature changes)?
- We still want to target 4.0 framework.  Is this an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure this answer's all your questions, but I think you can get a lot of information from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4

Comment: Thanks for that ... I'd already seen that page.  I don't think it'll be an issue, I just wanted to check to see if there were any hidden gotchas involved.